# Fresh install of CheckPoint Gaia r77 on VMware Workstation, no internet?

Tags: vmware-workstation, checkpoint

Hi I'm a complete noob to CP, Gaia and Firewalls.
I installed Gaia on VMware Workstation 12. I added 2 NIC on it:
First NIC is 10.34.x.x  Custom network and I seem to be able to manage Gaia through a Windows 7 Guest OS that uses the same network.
Second NIC is simply VMware NAT. I expected Gaia to access internet from here. But no I can't even get `ping google.com` result.
What am I missing?
Ps. I also tested VMware NAT network by installing a third VM guest, with same NAT network and yes it's working, it's got internet.

Any help is much obliged.

I'm guessing there must be a policy to allow internet connection to let Gaia Guest access the internet but as of now, no clue how to define it.